# Trying to understand deployment jobs in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm going through the docs of Azure Pipelines about deployment jobs and I feel like I'm missing something big time.
I'll explain what I understand so far, please correct me where I'm wrong:

A deployment job is used to deploy your application to different *Environments*. An environment is a set of *Resources* (VMs or a Kubernetes namespaces) that your application can be deployed into.

Normally (if not always) those resources are your servers that you want to deploy your application to.

In your Pipeline definition, a deployment job looks something like:

```
jobs:
  # Track deployments on the environment.
- deployment: DeployWeb
  displayName: deploy Web App
  pool:
    vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'

  # Creates an environment if it doesn't exist.
  environment: 'smarthotel-dev'
  strategy:
    # Default deployment strategy, more coming...
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - checkout: self 
        - script: echo my first deployment
```

From experience, if the environment doesn't contain any resources, this job will run on an agent from the pool specified. If it does, it will run on all resources in the environment.

Now there's something very basic that I'm missing here: Why on earth is there an option to run this deployment job with an environment that has no resources? What is the meaning of creating and using an "Environment" that has no resources? And why is there a `pool:` definition here that the job will run on one of its agents in that case? Isn't the whole point is deploying your application to one of your environments (and actually having those environments)?

I must say that the docs around this issue are very unclear.

Answer (score 3):

> Why on earth is there an option to run this deployment job with an environment that has no resources

Because environments are the scope at which you define pre-deployment checks (approvals, gates, etc).

Deploying to resources defined in an environment is an *option*, not a requirement.

As an example, if you have a serverless Azure web app, you use an environment to define the approvals and gates required to deploy to that environment, but then actual deployment activities occur on an agent from an agent pool because an Azure Web App doesn't have any physical machines to deploy to.

Comment: so the use of environments in this case is just a way to control the run of the job? So really the name of the environment doesn't have any meaning in that case? that sounds pretty weird..

Comment: The name of the environment has meaning. A "dev" environment might have looser or no restrictions. A "prod" environment might have extensive checks and approvals required prior to deployment. It just doesn't directly correspond to a set of physical hardware.

Comment: but there is no "environment", so what is the point of just artificially relating job runs to "dev", "test" and "prod" "environments"? These jobs all run on the same server as far as we concern. Maybe you mean that, a job that targets "prod" environment will update the application listening on the production port or something like this?

Comment: @YoavKlein You're hung up on *one* use case for environments. Environments are **more than just a set of servers**. They also tell Azure DevOps what approvals and gates are required to promote a build from one environment to the next. Look at the full set of capabilities of environments.

Comment: Work through solving this problem and you'll understand what I'm talking about: Let's say you have a pipeline that goes Build -> Deploy to Dev -> Deploy to Prod. You don't want to deploy to prod until after someone goes to Azure DevOps and approves the deployment. How do you accomplish this?

Comment: this is exactly where I fail to understand you - Assuming there is no "set of servers" - What does it mean "Deploy to Dev" ? What does it mean "Deploy to Prod"?

Comment: @YoavKlein It means whatever you want it to mean. Deployment jobs tie a job (which is a template or a set of steps) to an environment. An environment *can* (but doesn't *have to*) contain references to physical/virtual servers to run the job on. If you **don't have servers** (i.e. you're deploying to a serverless cloud application), an environment **still** allows you to configure all of the requirements (approvals, gates, status checks, etc) that have to be met before that deployment (regardless of what the deployment target is) can take place.